# Unexpected wide confidence intervals with lsmeans glm binomial

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

I have a dataset with 2 factors (sorte / meristemposition) and a binary response (0/1) and ran a glm model in R including the interactions:

```
modell<-glm(elisa ~ sorte + meristemposition 
            +sorte:meristemposition,
            data=data, family=binomial())
```

The ANOVA gave the following output - significances for sorte:meristemposition interaction:

```
anova(modell,test='LRT')
```

[image]

Now, that the interaction is significant, I wanted to calculate the lsmeans with the following code, including back-transformation with logit:

```
cld(lsmeans(modell, reformulate("sorte:meristemposition", 'pairwise'), type = "response",  adjust="tukey"))
```

This gave the following result - there were no significant differences found between any of the combinations, all came into the same group.

[image]

Then I had a closer look at the confidence intervals and the SE. In the last combination (gen3, spitze), there is a really low SE of 0.0000123, which is in accordance with the fact that in the raw data, all repeated observations of gen3 and "spitze" had an outcome of 1 - never was there any 0 in the binary response. So I expected a very narrow confidence interval. However, you can see that the confidence interval reaches from 0 to 1, which may then contribute to the non-significance of this combination compared to others.

How can this be explained?

Comment: You need to google "complete separation", when the outcome is perfectly predicted the model breaks down

Comment: Look at this same results with `type = "link"` and you'll see what you are up against. The SEs you see in your response-scale output are calculated using the delta method but are not used in the tests.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).